# Flutter Textfield Change "keyboardType: TextInputType" with Radio Button

Tags: flutter

In my application I have two radio buttons (number and email) and one textfield. What I want to do is this: when I click the number button, I want the keyboard to come up as a number input. When I click the email button on the same screen, I want the my device keyboard to change to email format. I'm new. Can you help with a code snippet?

(What I want to do is pictured below)

[image]

[image]

This is my example code:

```
...
RadioListTile(
                                title: Text(‘NUMBER’,
                                value: _value, 
                                groupValue: numberClick ?? _value,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _value = value.toString();
                                    numberClick = true;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
RadioListTile(
                                title: Text(‘EMAIL’,
                                value: _value, 
                                groupValue: numberClick ?? _value,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _value = value.toString();
                                    numberClick = false;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),

...   
TextField( 
                
                keyboardType: numberClick ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.emailAddress,
              ),
```

...

NOTE: I'm having a poblem with this part:

```
TextField( 
                
                keyboardType: numberClick ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.emailAddress,
              )
```

Comment: can you provide a bit more details/ code snippets on radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this

```
 FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                setState(() {
                  if (widget._inputType == TextInputType.number)
                    widget._inputType = TextInputType.text;
                  else
                    widget._inputType = TextInputType.number;
                });
```

in your radio button you need to unfocus your keyboard otherwise it wont change

Answer (score 0):

You can change based upon the group value of the radio button, to do that you can use and modify the following code for your radio buttons.

```
Radio(
          value: 1,
          groupValue: _selectedValue,
          onChanged: (int value){
             number_click = true;
             setState(() {
                _selectedValue = value;
               });
          },
        ),
        Text('Number'),
        Radio(
          value: 2,
          groupValue: _selectedValue,
          onChanged: (int value){
             number_click = false;
             setState(() {
                _selectedValue = value;
               });
           },
        ),
        Text('Email'),
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I want the keyboard of the device to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Fatih Demir you can have Two different TextField for different purposes. You can show specific Text Field on radio button click

You can do like this

```
numberClick ? TextField(keyboardType:  TextInputType.number ) : TextField( keyboardType:  TextInputType.emailAddress,)
```

Please let me know if your problem is solved

Comment: I tried but it didn't work :( what I want is for the device keyboard to refresh itself. When I click on the Email button, the keyboard should automatically change to email format. TextField is being refreshed but the keyboard doesn't change :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
numberClick
   ? TextField(keyboardType: TextInputType.number)
   : TextField(keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress),
```

Comment: I want is for the device keyboard to refresh itself. When I click on the Email button, the keyboard should automatically change to email format. TextField is being refreshed but the keyboard doesn't change

Comment: use obx  widget for instent state change in you device